# WbCmd Movesense: Trouble With Putting Objects

Tags: movesense

I'm testing on Windows with PowerShell.

When I put simple types like `bool`, WbCmd works like expected.

```
PS> wbcmd --port TCP7044 --path /Component/Led --op put --opdatatype bool --opdata true
WbCmd Movesense:
{
  "response": 200,
  "responsestring": "HTTP_CODE_OK",
  "operation": "put",
  "uri": "/net/ECSI00000000/Component/Led",
  "querytimems": 0,
  "querytimens": 536100
}
```

But when I try to put an object, it "fails to find the data type."

```
PS> wbcmd --port TCP7044 --path /Component/Leds/0 --op get
WbCmd Movesense:
{
  "response": 200,
  "responsestring": "HTTP_CODE_OK",
  "operation": "get",
  "uri": "/net/ECSI00000000/Component/Leds/0",
  "content": {
    "IsOn": true,
    "LedColor": [
      0,
      "Red"
    ]
  },
  "querytimems": 0,
  "querytimens": 613500
}

PS> wbcmd --port TCP7044 --path /Component/Leds/0 --op put --opdatatype LedState --opdata '{ "LedState":
{ "IsOn": false, "LedColor": 0 } }'
WbCmd Movesense:
{
  "response": 404,
  "responsestring": "Failed to find data type LedState",
  "operation": "put",
  "uri": "/net/ECSI00000000/Component/Leds/0",
  "querytimems": 3,
  "querytimens": 3526200
}
```

How can I fix that or get more information about what happens in the background?

Comment: I think you have to remove the wrapper and just include the inner part of the object

Comment: ... in that way the wbcmd works a bit different from MDS. In MDS there needs to be the wrapper with correct property name (=parameter name). In wbcmd you just give the parameter object(s)

Comment: @user1987093 It doesn't matter what the content of `--opdata` is as long as it exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are two led API's in the Movesense sensor. The simple /Component/Led with a true/false value (matching the single led in current Movesense sensor). The second LED API has beed added to support multiple / multicolor LED's that are found in other Movesense compatible devices.

For Movesense sensor I'd recommend using the simple API. However to put to the complex API using wbcmd, use the following command (I've tested and it works, did in Mac, that's why the port looks like that):

```
wbcmd --port /dev/cu.usbserial-AL01XHQC --path /component/leds/0 --op put --opdata '{"IsOn":true}'
```

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: That gives me the error `HTTP_CODE_BAD_REQUEST`. In general, this might be an issue with WbCmd on Windows specifically. But because the simulator only runs on Windows, I can't easily change my development system.